# Trying to build ARPACK, but many source files are not being compiled

Tags: fortran, gfortran, intel-fortran, msys2, arpack

Let me start by saying I am not a superuser and somewhat of a noob here, but I have a basic understanding of what I'm doing.

I have installed MSYS2 and MinGW-w64 following the directions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069830/how-to-install-mingw-w64-and-msys2?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa). I am working on 64-bit Windows 10, and I want to ultimately utilize the [ARPACK](http://www.caam.rice.edu/software/ARPACK/) library in my Fortran 90 code. I am currently using Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 and the Intel Fortran ifort compiler and MKL libraries. So,

**1.** Should I compile ARPACK with `gfortran` or `ifort`, or does it not matter?

**Addendum:** compiling with `ifort` seems be creating a lot of headaches, in particular because the commands referenced in the `ARmake.inc` file are unix commands, so I would need to replace them with Windows equivalents which I am not that familiar with (e.g. `ln -s` -> `mklink`)

I have extracted the ARPACK source files to `/c/ARPACK`, and I have updated the `ARmake.inc` file, changing the following:

```
home = /c/ARPACK
PLAT = x64
FC = gfortran
```

I also went into the `/UTIL/second.f` file and removed the line `EXTERNAL ETIME()`.

**2.** should I set `PLAT = x86_64`? I don't understand exactly how `make` works, so I don't know what exactly this setting is going to affect. I am running `make` from within the `mingw64` shell (run from the `/msys64` folder).

Next, I run `make lib`. I get a number of warnings, in particular while compiling `snrm2.f` and `dnrm2.f`, I get the same errors:

```
snrm2.f:56:72:

    10 assign 30 to next
                                                                        1
Warning: Deleted feature: ASSIGN statement at (1)
snrm2.f:62:19:

    20    go to next,(30, 50, 70, 110)
                   1
Warning: Deleted feature: Assigned GOTO statement at (1)
snrm2.f:64:72:

       assign 50 to next
                                                                        1
Warning: Deleted feature: ASSIGN statement at (1)
snrm2.f:73:72:

       assign 70 to next
                                                                        1
Warning: Deleted feature: ASSIGN statement at (1)
snrm2.f:79:72:

       assign 110 to next
                                                                        1
Warning: Deleted feature: ASSIGN statement at (1)
```

**3.** Are these warnings important? My Fortran 77 knowledge is pretty minimal and I haven't tried very hard to understand them.

Further, every time it enters a new folder I get (for example)

```
make[1]: Leaving directory '/c/ARPACK/BLAS'
Making lib in /c/ARPACK/LAPACK
make[1]: Entering directory '/c/ARPACK/LAPACK'
Makefile:91: warning: overriding recipe for target '.f.o'
../ARmake.inc:95: warning: ignoring old recipe for target '.f.o'
gfortran -O  -c sgeqr2.f
gfortran -O  -c slabad.f
gfortran -O  -c slacon.f
.....
```

where the `ARmake.inc` file has

```
90   # %-------------------------------------------%
91   # |  Command to build .o files from .f files. |
92   # %-------------------------------------------%
93   #
94   .f.o:
95       @$(ECHO) Making $@ from $<
96       @$(FC) -c $(FFLAGS) $<
```

**4.** Is this warning/error message important? My understanding is this should print for example

```
    Making sgeqr2.o from sgeqr2.f
    gfortran -O  -c sgeqr2.f
```

but `make` isn't liking that there are two commands here, and is overwriting the first with the second.

Finally to wrap it all up, before I go any further I noticed that not every one of the source `.f` files have been compiled. For example, in `/BLAS`, I have `cgemm.f`, `ctbsv.f`, `ctrsm.f`, `dgemm.f`, and a number of others which do not have associated `.o` files. Why have these been left out? I know that `dgemm` for example is a pretty  basic matrix multiplication routine which I think is essential, so I am assuming there has been an error somewhere along the line, but I never saw any error messages during the `make` process. Any and all help appreciated, after many many hours of trying to get this to work I feel that the end is (hopefully) in sight. So my final and most important question

<s>**5.** Why did some of the source files not compile, and is this going to prevent the resulting library from being usable? If so what could I have done differently or what do I need to do to finish building the library?</s>

I realize that the individual `Makefile`'s mention that these files are not required by ARPACK but are required for ARPACK examples. They can be included by using `make all` instead of `make lib`.

Comment: Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. Much more people will see your question. You can choose a different choice of tags than I chose but keep the fortran tag.

Comment: What you show in 2. are *warnings*, NOT *errors*. Warnings do not cause compilation failure unless you use special options. We may have questions about those, did you try to search? I don't think they are important now.

Comment: I used arpack-ng before and worked fine for me (in contrast to the original Rice one) https://github.com/opencollab/arpack-ng Also I think prebuilt arpack is often available via various routes(homebrew/linuxbrew/Ubuntu/...), which may be easier to try (also for windows this may be related https://github.com/Alexpux/MINGW-packages/blob/master/mingw-w64-arpack/PKGBUILD )

Comment: @roygvib, this looks promising, but I can't figure out how to build it due to lack of BLAS and LAPACK libraries, do you have any pointers to how I could perhaps link it to the Intel MKL libraries? Or an alternative?

Comment: MKL has its own BLAS and LAPACK internally, so I think it should be sufficient to just link MKL (in the case of Linux + ifort, -mkl option). I guess a similar option for Windows + MKL. In the case of gfortran, we need a bit more options... https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mkl-link-line-advisor (Also many distros have their builtin BLAS/LAPACK very often, so just -lblas -llapack -L/usr/some/where ...)

Comment: I tried using -lblas and -llapack with gfortran, it compiles but on execution gives an error. I posted a separate question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49783733/using-blas-lapack-and-arpack-with-msys2)