# Using BLAS, LAPACK, and ARPACK with MSYS2

Tags: fortran, gfortran, lapack, blas, msys2

I am working on Windows 10 64-bit using MSYS2 with the 64-bit toolchain. In the MSYS2 terminal I found and installed the following packages after searching for them with `pacman -Ss`,

```
mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-openblas 0.2.20-2
mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-lapack 3.6.1-1
mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-arpack 3.5.0-1
```

I took an example fortran source file from the Intel MKL library examples; I copied the `dgelsx.f` file to a folder in my msys home directory. I compile (in the `mingw64` terminal) with

```
gfortran dgelsx.f -o dgelsx -llapack -lblas
```

it compiles without any complaint, but when I attempt to run it, I get the error

```
C:/msys64/home/k_chu/lapacktext/dgelsx.exe: error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Why is this happening? I haven't attempted to deal with an `arpack` example yet until I get this working. Also if I do get all of this working, will it be possible to use the `arpack` libraries in Microsoft Visual Studio with the Intel `ifort` compiler? I tried copying the `.dll` files in `/msys64/mingw64/bin` into my MSV project folder but no luck, same with the `.a` and `.dll.a` files in the `/msys64/mingw64/lib`.

Answer (score -1):

Please use dependency walker (http://www.dependencywalker.com) to locate the .dll, which the program cannot find on the path. Or compile with `-static-libgcc` or `-static-libstdc++` to avoid dependencies at runtime.